# Left Join not producing nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like this :

```
website_session_id  landing_page
'1',                '/home'
'2',                '/home'
'3',                '/home'
'4',                '/home'
'5',                '/home'
'6',                '/home'
'7',                '/home'
'8',                '/home'
'9',                '/home'
'10',               '/home'



website_session_id      
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
'7'
'8'
'9'
'10'
```

I am using LEFT Join to connect both table, the website_session_id with value 6 is not shown at all.Isnt it supposed to show something like

```
6     /home    NULL
```

SQL QUERY :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    session_first_view
        LEFT JOIN
    bounced_sessions ON session_first_view.website_session_id =  bounced_sessions.website_session_id
```

[image]

Comment: If this is the full query and `session_first_view` is the first table (could you label each one?), it should work, unless you are using some condition in WHERE using the second table.

Comment: Privet @F.Igor, That is the query I am using, and those are the two tables.
I am not sure why its not doing it

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? I reproduced the scenario and obtain the `null` value as expected. (https://telegra.ph/file/d6740840797fecf2333da.png)
The result you're presenting matches a JOIN and not a LEFT JOIN. 
Could you double-check the code?

Comment: I am using left join, but result are of inner join.Its strange. I am using version 8

Comment: Well, the only other thing that occurs to me is to reproduce the exact scenario; so edit the question and include table details like indexes, nulls, etc. Also, you are showing an item with ID 11 on the sample results which is no present on the source. Please sync the sample with your run just to be sure.

Comment: Pro tip: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, but is it creating the issue here ?

Comment: Well yes, because you have two columns with the same name.

Comment: @Strawberry , Thanks comrade, this cleared my confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the table name : assume First Table Name is T1 and second Table is T2 the join condition is as below , wherein T1 has 2 column as mentioned

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    T1
        LEFT JOIN
    T2 ON T1.website_session_id =  T2.website_session_id
```

Comment: this is exactly what I did

Answer (score -1):

If your first table is `session_first_view` it should work

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81e8b06/1

Unless the first table effectively has no record with website_session_id='6'.
Please check your table data.

Also, you can check if you are getting null results using

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    session_first_view
        LEFT JOIN
    bounced_sessions ON session_first_view.website_session_id =  
bounced_sessions.website_session_id 
WHERE bounced_sessions.id IS NULL
```

It should display at least this one with `website_session_id='6'`

Comment: Even I know it should work,but for some reason its not showing up. :/

Comment: Any other filter before showing results? (Your capture is the direct result of the query?)

Comment: yes, The content of the table are the final result for running the queries.

Comment: There are more results? (the resulting data could not be sorted the same way as any of the tables, and the record could be at the end of the data. Try checking nulls as well